# How to add Exits or Exit rate as an Objective in Google Optimize

Tags: optimization

Is there way to add Exits or Exit rate as an Objective in Google Optimize?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I found answer as below and sharing this.

You don’t necessarily have to set this metric as the objective for your experiment. If you have hooked up Google Analytics to your Google Optimize account, which is a requirement to run Google Optimize so I’m assuming you have.

What you can do in Google Analytics is to create a custom report filtered down on the Experiment Name. After that, you can compare based on the Experiment Variant. This will give you the ability to select all the metrics that are useful for you and the data that you want to see in there.

The custom report would look something like this, in Google Analytics:

[google analytics custom report set up to get exits or exit rate in google optimize ab test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JL27.png)

Original Source: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-set-the-exit-rate-as-the-objective-of-the-A-B-test-or-the-redirect-test-in-Google-Optimize